# How to use sqlalchemy to select data from a database?

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have two sqlalchemy scripts, one that creates a database and a few tables and another that selects data from them.

**create_database.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey, select
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()

addresses = Table ('addresses', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', None, ForeignKey('users.id')),
    Column('email_addresses', String, nullable=False)
)

users = Table ('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('fullname', String),
)

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

**select.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)

conn = engine.connect()
s = select([users])
result = conn.execute(s)
```

I am able to run the **create_database.py** script but when I run the **select.py** script I get the following error

```
$ python select.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "select.py", line 5, in <module>
    s = select([users])
```

I am able to run the select statement from within the **create_database.py** by appending the following to **create_database.py**

```
conn = engine.connect()
s = select([users])
result = conn.execute(s)
```

How can I run the select statements from a separate script than **create_database.py**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script `select.py` does not see `users` and `addresses` defined in `create_database.py`. Import them in `select.py` before using them.

In `select.py`:

```
from create_database import users, addresses

## Do something with users and addresses
```